# readXlsxFile reading excel sheets out of order in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am using the below code to read and populate my map. but the sheets data is read out of order even after applying promises to  the code. so the 2 keys data (key is sheet Name) is exchanged.

async function getSheetRows(sheetIndexMap, file) {

```
let sheetRowsMap = {};
const promises = sheetIndexMap.map(async (sheet) => {
  return {
    sheetName: sheet.name,
    sheetRows: await readXlsxFile(file, { sheet:sheet.name})
  }
})
const sheetRowsByResources = await Promise.all(promises);
sheetRowsByResources.forEach (sheetRowsByResource => {
  sheetRowsMap[sheetRowsByResource.sheetName] = sheetRowsByResource.sheetRows
})
return sheetRowsMap
```

}

```
async function getResourceDataMap(stationCode, event) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      let sheetIndexMap = await readXlsxFile(file, { getSheets : true} );
      let resourceDataMap = {};
      const sheetRowsMap = await getSheetRows(sheetIndexMap, file);
      /*
           Consider all the sheets
           */
        Object.keys(sheetRowsMap).map((sheetName) => {
        if(isSheetNameValid(sheetName)) {
          console.log("Entered for sheetName::" + sheetName);
          let sheetRows = sheetRowsMap[sheetName];
          console.log("sheet Rows for:::::" +sheetName + " are " + sheetRows.length);
          if (sheetRows != null && sheetRows.length > 1) { // we need atleast two rows
              let headers = sheetRows[0];
              console.log("header obtained is:" +headers);

              if(isColumnNamesValid(sheetName, headers)) {
                  let sheetMapList = getSheetMap(sheetRows);
                  console.log("SheetMapList obtained is:" + sheetMapList);

                  // STEP : Create a map of the various sheets (corresponding to each resource type)
                  console.log("SheetName here is::::::::" +sheetName);
                  resourceDataMap[sheetName] = {
                      headerRows: headers,
                      sheetMapList : sheetMapList
                  };
                  console.log("Resource data Map within :" + resourceDataMap["PRE_STAGING_AREA"]);
              }
          }
        }
      }) 
      return resourceDataMap;
```

}

Please help!!!!

Comment: The issue was with the read-excel-file node plugin version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the read-excel-file node plugin version. I changed it from 3.x to 4.x.